# ASP.NET: Ajax doesn't send string

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I have this method to send some data with ajax:

```
function SendData(foodID, basketID) {
    var data = { FoodID: foodID, BasketID: basketID };

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Order/Post',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: 'application/json;utf-8',
        datatype: 'json'
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }).fail(function (data) {
        console.log("Error: " + data);
    });
}
```

In C#, my `Post` Method in my `Order` controller gets triggered, but the string I want to hand over is null:

```
public bool Post(string s)
{
    //When this gets executed, s is null
    return true;
}
```

I tested this by executing `SendData(1,1)` directly on a button click. What is the mistake I'm doing and how can I get the string in my Post-Method?

Comment: have you tried without stringify?

`data: data,`

Comment: That doesn't help either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are post the object. not string.

you can try generate to object and load this object. or add new one parameter to action (foodId and basketId but you must post like that if you check this option `data:{foodId,basketId}`)

```
//model
    public class SomeObject{
public string FoodId {get;set;}
public string BasketId {get;set;}
}

//code
public bool Post(SomeObject data)
{
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems for me your data structure to the Post action doesn't match action parameter names. Try this:

```
[HttpPost]
public bool Post(string foodID, string baskedID)
{
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to name your data that's being passed like so:

```
 data: { 's': JSON.stringify(data) }
```